# Unable to show a popup of choose file while clicking on upload file in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to reactjs, have created a file upload UI, when i click on pin icon or in the fileupload name field it is not asking to browse files. My objective is when we click on the pin button it should show our file folder for to choose file. i couldn't figure it out where i'm going wrong. Can anyone help me where i'm going wrong?

This is the code:

```
<>
        <div className="fileInput">
          <Input
            type="text"
            placeholder="File 1"
            id="file-path"
            readonly
            name="fileName"
            value={this.state.fileName}
          />
          <Input
            type="file"
            id="file-id"
            name="file"
            onChange={this.FileUpload}
          />
          <Button icon="paperclip" />
        </div>
        <Button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Submit</Button>
      </>
```

[Here is the full Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-wood-xwm6y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution:

Just add `onClick` function for your button and then manually click input.

```
  openFile = () => {
    document.getElementById("file-id").click();
  };
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-shamir-5j9x5)

also use can use `React ref`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass some props to your `<Button icon="paperclip" />` to refer to your file Input

```
<Input
 type="file"
 id="file-id"
 name="file"
 onChange={this.FileUpload}
/>

<Button icon="paperclip" as="label" htmlFor="file-id" />
```

Comment: Hi, I'll try to pass props. Thanks for providing solution to my query :)